# Como fazer para dois eventos não dispararem ao mesmo tempo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Preciso fazer um menu que ao clicar no botão ele aparece e quando clicar fora ele desaparece. 
 
O problema que eu venho enfrentando é que o evento para fazer sumir o menu é o se torna o mesmo de aparecer, dessa forma ele entra num pequeno loop.
Como fazer para não ativar os dois eventos ao mesmo tempo?
HTML e JavaScript abaixo.

```js
$("#btn-menu").click(function (){
  $('.btn-menu').hide('slow');
  $('.div-nav-menu').show('slow');
});
$('body').click(function (){
  if(document.getElementById('1010').style.display == "block"){
    $('.div-nav-menu').hide('slow');
    $('.btn-menu').show('slow');
  }
  else{
    return (false);
  }
});
```

```css
.div-nav-menu{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(65deg, #ff1414 15% , #002874 50%);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: -250px;
    right: -250px;
    display: none;
}
.btn-menu{
    width: 53px;
    height: 53px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(65deg, #ff1414, #002874);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
    margin-right: 260px;
    margin-top: 76px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-menu">
  <button class="btn-menu" id="btn-menu">menu</button>
  <div class="div-nav-menu" id="1010">
    <nav class="nav-menu">
      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu não rodei seu código aqui mas pelo que eu vi está acontecendo a seguinte coisa.

No seu código tem 2 event listeners. O primeiro `#btn-menu` está ligado somente ao elemento com esse id. O segundo 'body' está ligado a toda página html. Todo evento que ocorrer dentro do body esse segundo listener vai pegar. Então, sempre que ocorrer o primeiro evento vai ocorrer o segundo de qualquer forma.

Você pode fazer a seguinte coisa:

```
$('body').click(function (ev){
  if(document.getElementById('1010').style.display == "block" and ev.target.id != "btn-menu"){
    $('.div-nav-menu').hide('slow');
    $('.btn-menu').show('slow');
  }
  else{
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Neste caso eu verifico se quem disparou o evento não foi o botão e assim eu só desapareço o menu caso o click não tenha sido no botão.

Deu para entender?

Comment: Deu sim. Vou verificar e te retorno.

Answer (score 1):

Tente colocar o código e.stopImmediatePropagation(); nessa forma:

```
$("#btn-menu").click(function (e){

  e.stopImmediatePropagation();

});
```

Assim as outras funções vão parar de executar automaticamente.